# Python. Не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста

Tags: python

> Необходимо решить с использованием методов строк.
>
> Дана строка. Выясните, какое слово встречается раньше в строке – на
> букву "K" или на букву "I". Предполагается, что в строке есть слова,
> начинающиеся как с буквы "K", так и с буквы "I".
>
> Входные данные
>
> Строка, состоящая из заглавных латинских букв, пробелов и знаков
> препинания.
>
> Выходные данные
>
> Выведите первое слово, начинающееся на букву "K", если оно стоит
> раньше первого слово, начинающегося на букву "I", или первое слово,
> начинающееся на букву "I", если оно стоит раньше первого слово,
> начинающегося на букву "K".
>
> Пример
>
> Входные данные
>
> KATE COOKS IN THE KITCHEN.
>
> Выходные данные
>
> KATE

```
str = input().split()
for i in str:
        if i[0] == "K":
            s = i
            break
        elif i[0] == "I":
            s = i
            break
print(s)
```

Comment: А что именно не работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот та же логика, но с использованием метода `startswith`, который проверяет, что строка начинается с указанной подстроки:

```
words = input().split()
for w in words:
    if w.startswith("K"):
        print(w)
        break
    elif w.startswith("I"):
        print(w)
        break
```

или вот более лаконичный вариант:

```
words = input().split()

result = next(
    w for w in words
    if w.startswith("K") or w.startswith("I")
)

print(result)
```

Comment: Метод может принимать варианты строк: `w.startswith(('K', 'I'))` :)